# reference s3 in docker run command

Tags: docker

I am trying to test a local `docker` image using content from different `s3` buckets and getting:

`docker: invalid reference format`

The `ec2` can see the `s3` buckets and I am able to ls and `cp` the content in them, but the files are large so I am tying to aviod the `-v` and referencing the file local. . Thank you :).

```
docker run <image> HaplotypeCaller  \
 -R <s3_bucket1> \
 -I <s3_bucket2> \
 -L <s3_bucket3> \
 -O <s3_bucket1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse to mount the S3 bucket, then bind the volume and use it in your Docker container like this:

```
jdsalaro$ sudo apt install s3fs
```

or on OSx:

```
brew install --cask osxfuse
brew install s3fs
```

Then mount your S3 bucket and run your container with the mount point as a volume:

```
jdsalaro$ s3fs helloworld /tmp/s3fs/
jdsalaro$ docker run -v /tmp/s3fs/:/tmp/s3fs alpine ls -Rl /tmp/
```

```
/tmp/:
total 1
drwx------    1 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 s3fs

/tmp/s3fs:
total 1
drwxr-x---    1 root     root             0 Dec  9 22:17 helloworld

/tmp/s3fs/helloworld:
total 0
```